# Python: CountVectorizer ignores one letter word "I"

Tags: python, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I have a list called `dictionary1`. I use the following code to get sparse count matrices of texts:

```
cv1 = sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer(stop_words=None)  
cv1.fit_transform(dictionary1)
```

I notice however that

```
list(set(dictionary1)-set(cv1.get_feature_names()))
```

results in  `['i']`. So "i" is in my dictionary but `CountVectorizer` ignores it (presumably some default setting discards one-char words). In the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.fit_transform) I could not find such an option. Can someone point me to the problem? Indeed I would like to keep "i" in my analysis, as it could refer to more personal language.

Comment: have you tried it with `stop_words=[]` yet?

Comment: results in the same issue if I replace "None" with "[]"

Comment: Well, then it's not because of maxdf. Next try would be writing your own tokenizing regex, after making sure you pass `analyzer='word'` for sure.. do you know how to do that?

Comment: not quite; I assume you mean using the token_pattern option with a suitable regex, as the default requires two or more char for a word token?

Comment: @SAFEX Yes. You can change the default token_pattern to include 1 letter words.

Comment: @VivekKumar: Indeed! For reference the appropriate setting is "token_pattern = r"(?u)\b\w+\b" where "r"(?u)\b\w+\b" is a regular expression which allows for one character words.

Answer (score 1):

A working work-around is passing the dictionary as the vocabulary directly (actually I don't know why I did not do thath in the first place). I.e.

```
cv1 = sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer(stop_words=[], vocabulary=dictionary1)
cv1._validate_vocabulary()
```

`list(set(dictionary1)-set(cv1.get_feature_names()))` then returns `[]`.

In my original post, I should have mentioned that `dictionary1` already is a list of unique tokens.

Answer (score 0):

> The default configuration tokenizes the string by extracting words of at least 2 letters.

Check out [this link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#common-vectorizer-usage) to see more details about sklearn vectorizers.

In your case, you should use a different ***tokenizer***, not analyzer. For example, you can use TweetTokenizer from `nltk` library:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer

corpus = [...some_texts...]

tk = TweetTokenizer()
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tk.tokenize)
x = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
```

For example, if `corpus` is defined as below, you would get:

```
corpus = ['I love ragdolls',
          'I received a cat',
          'I take it as my best friend']

vectorizer.get_feature_names()

> ['a', 'as', 'best', 'cat', 'friend', 'i', 'it', 'love', 'my', 'ragdolls', 'received', 'take']
```